# Read and view tab-delimited txt files in Qt C++ using QTableView

Tags: qt, qtableview, qfile, csv

I need some general advice to point me in the correct direction of solving this problem: I have a .txt file with table data like the following:

```
Time    Pin
11:00   EIO4
12:55   EIO6
16:40   EIO4
20:10   EIO3

etc......
```

I need to be able to parse this .txt file. Then I need to display this table in Qt (perhaps in a `QTableView`).

I have looked into using QTableView, and it appears I pass a `QAbstractItemModel*` to the `QTableView` using `QTableView::setModel(QAbstractItemModel* model)`, after which my QTableView will display whatever data is in the QAbstractItemModel (right?).

If that last paragraph was logical, then my next question is how do I construct a `QAbstractItemModel` using my .txt file? I don't see any functions in the documentation that do this? (Note: someone suggested creating a QStandardItemModel)

(Note, this paragraph is no longer relevant) `QModelIndex createIndex(int row, int column, void* ptr)` appears to have something to do with this, maybe? Maybe this creates a `QModelIndex` that can be passed to the `QAbstractItemModel` using `QAbstractItemModel::insertRow(QModelIndex)`? However I still don't know how to make these `QModelIndex` objects have anything to do with my .txt data.

`QStandardItemModel` documentation says

> When you want a list or tree, you typically create an empty
>   `QStandardItemModel` and use `appendRow()` to add items to the model, and
>   `item()` to access an item. If your model represents a table, you
>   typically pass the dimensions of the table to the `QStandardItemModel`
>   constructor and use `setItem()` to position items into the table. You
>   can also use `setRowCount()` and `setColumnCount()` to alter the
>   dimensions of the model. To insert items, use `insertRow()` or
>   `insertColumn()`, and to remove items, use `removeRow()` or
>   `removeColumn()`.

These functions that "add rows" take `QList<QStandardItem*>`'s as arguments, so I need to create QLists that each contain pointers QStandardItems that contain each cell's data?

So I will use

```
void QStandardItemModel::insertRow(int row, const QList<QStandardItem *> & items)
```

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#insertRow

Along with an argument `QList<QStandardItem*>` generated by repeated calls of "`<<`" passing `QStandardItem*` pointers to an empty `QList`.

I will make `QStandardItem`'s using the constructor

```
QStandardItem::QStandardItem(const QString & text)
```

where I get my `QString text` by parsing a QFile into QStrings.

Everything looking good?

Or maybe I should skip creating QLists and go directly from generating `QStandardItem`'s to passing them into the `QStandardItemModel` using `void QStandardItemModel::setItem(int row, int column, QStandardItem * item)`

Edit:
I ended up skipping creating QLists with the following process:
QFile file -> QString line -> QStringList peices -> QStandardItem -> QStandardItemModel -> QTableView

Thanks to all who contributed

Comment: You can't create an abstract model, it's abstract.  You'll need to subclass it.  You might take a look at the docs for more information about that: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html

Comment: I looked, it says my QAbstractTableModel subclass must implement `QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const`, but I don't know how to make QModelIndex objects that have anything to do with my .txt file?! I added a paragraph to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. You can use [QStandardItemModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html) for your data.

```
QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(2,3,this);
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, new QStandardItem(QString("Column1 Header")));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, new QStandardItem(QString("Column2 Header")));
model->setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, new QStandardItem(QString("Column3 Header")));

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

Than you can add values:

```
QStandardItem *firstRow = new QStandardItem(QString("ColumnValue"));
model->setItem(0,0,firstRow);
```

Comment: This is not an answer, it is comment worthy at best.

Answer (score 0):

For the original question, i.e. how to create a custom model: this is fairly easy because there is a convenience base class for table models, `QAbstractTableModel` which implements most of the hairy methods of the general model interface.

The first step for a custom table model is to decide on a data type for a single row, e.g.

```
struct Data
{
    QTime time;
    QString pin;
};
```

The custom model can then operate on a list or vector of that type.

```
class MyModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
private:
    QVector<Data> m_data;
};
```

The `rowCount()` method can then simply be implemented by returning the size/count of the list/vector, `columnCount()` is fixed (2 in this example) and `data()` can simply access the n-th entry and switch on requested column:

```
QVariant MyModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    const Data &rowData = m_data[index.row()];

    switch (index.row()) {
    case 0: {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) return rowData.time.toString("hh:mm"); // or whatever format you'd like
        else if (role == Qt::EditRole) return rowData.time; // return as QTime
        break;
    }
    case 1: if (role == Qt::DisplayRole || role == Qt::EditRole) return rowData.pin;
        break;
    default: break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}
```

Optionally implement `headerData()` to to get "Time" and "PIN" as the column headers